# Highcharts column graph, how to hide bottom border?

Tags: highcharts

I'm struggling to find a way to hide the bottom border of the dashed column. Is there a way to do this?

[image]

Also, is there a way to make the dashed border look always the same on the corners? It's arbitrary at the moment, which doesn't look great.

Comment: could you provide an example in http://jsfiddle.net/ or simmilar? Btw, you could use jQuery to edit any attributes of each element in highcharts.

Comment: In the SVG the dash is applied for all path so you cannot define a "equal strokes" in corners. Only what you can do is modify dashstyle. Supported dashStyle you can find [here](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.area.dashStyle)

Comment: thanks, I managed to get away from the issue by applying smaller dash and covering the bottom border with zIndex.